# Substitute values in multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
ID  Situation 

1      Active
1      Active
1      Other
2      Active
2      Away
2      Active
3      Away
3      Away
3      Away
```

I want to replace the values in the situation column following the order Other > Active > Away so the resulting data frame looks like

```
ID  Situation 

1      Other
1      Other
1      Other
2      Active
2      Active
2      Active
3      Away
3      Away
3      Away
```

I think I should do a group_by first, but after this I'm having trouble thinking of what should I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', an option would be to convert the 'Situation to a `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order, then select the `first` `level` after dropping the unused `levels` (`droplevels`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Situation = factor(Situation, levels = c("Other", "Active", "Away")),
     Situation = levels(droplevels(Situation))[1]) 
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Situation
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 Other    
#2     1 Other    
#3     1 Other    
#4     2 Active   
#5     2 Active   
#6     2 Active   
#7     3 Away     
#8     3 Away     
#9     3 Away
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
 Situation = c("Active", 
"Active", "Other", "Active", "Away", "Active", "Away", "Away", 
"Away")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```